# should I store data with sql or Json when I am using Node.js for a web application

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I just started programming with node.js and before this I was using PHP and I used to store data on sql database. However, I am confused now. Should I use sql to save data or Json. I would need to save data and show them on the web page later on Or feed those data to draw graphs and charts.

Comment: What you use to store the data depends on the data and structure... not the language you use to handle it.

Answer (score 5):

When storing data in a Node.js application (or with any application really), you have three main options...

#### Memory

- You can simply store the data as a variable in the application, this
  will most likely be fastest to access.
- You may start to encounter problems if you are storing lots of data
  as you will use up a large proportion of your machine's memory.
- All data will be lost when the script restarts, so the data should be
  able to be generated again on startup.
- If you use a process manager like PM2 (which you'll want to do if
  hosting on a multi-core machine, see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04), you won't be able to store data across multiple requests as processes will not share a common memory.

#### I/O

- You could also encode data as JSON and store it in a file on your machine.
- I can't think of a case where this would be better than using a DB, I/O is usually just used for static files like images.
- The obvious drawback of this is that it will probably be slower than database calls but you'd also have to watch out for I/O concurrency issues if you're using miultiple processes.
- However, if you really want to store JSON, consider a non-relational DB like Mongo DB instead.

#### Database

- This would be my preferred method for almost every case (apart from static files or very short-lived data, as I mentioned above).
- A DB also has helpful ways of storing and finding data - you'll need to choose between a relational or non-relational DB, take a look at https://www.mongodb.com/scale/relational-vs-non-relational-database for some of the differences.
- Again, the main thing to be wary of is concurrency when using multiple processes (usually only a problem when updating or inserting records).

I hope that covers your question - I may have missed something but I'm sure others will let me know if I have. Node.js is a great choice for web servers as it is asynchronous so can naturally handle multiple connections at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can considered this args :

- SQL databases are relational, and NoSQL databases are non-relational.
- SQL databases use structured query language (SQL) and have a predefined schema. NoSQL databases have dynamic schemas for unstructured data.
- SQL databases are vertically scalable, while NoSQL databases are horizontally scalable.
- SQL databases are table-based, while NoSQL databases are document, key-value, graph, or wide-column stores.
- SQL databases are better for multi-row transactions, while NoSQL is better for unstructured data like documents or JSON.
  source : [explanation about SQL vs no SQL](https://www.integrate.io/blog/the-sql-vs-nosql-difference/)